# How can I merge 3 variable in to one variable

Tags: c++, c

I've problem to merge 3 variable become in to one variable:

example :

```
int var1,var2,var3;
int result;
var1 = 1;
var2 = 2;
var3 = 3;

result = ........??;

printf("Result %d",result);

output :
123
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want a C solution or a C++ solution? They are not the same language.

Comment: Why would you do this? Homework? If so, tag it that way. (Strike that... don't do that!)

Comment: @tmpearce:  The [homework] tag has been banned.

Comment: @tmpearce The homework tag is dead, don't use, don't tell others to use it.

Comment: @JohnDibling Ah... interesting, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I'd think you make a big step forward if you clarify (even just to yourself) what "this" is meant to say exactly!

Comment: what size are the vars? are they all-wayes one digit?

Comment: @tmpearce this not [homework], but this is my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yay, C++11 variadic templates are awesome! Here's a `N`-finitely expandable version, assuming `sum(args) < INT_MAX`

```
template<int max, int ...arguments>
int merge_integers()
{
    int args[] = { arguments... };
    int size = sizeof(args) / sizeof(int);
    int mul = 1;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = size; i--; )
    {
        result += args[i] * mul;
        mul *= max;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
printf("%d\n", merge_integers<10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1>());
printf("%x\n", merge_integers<16, 0xA, 0xB, 0x1, 0x3, 0x5>());
printf("%o\n", merge_integers<8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7>());
```

Output:

```
54321
ab135
12347
```

Answer (score 5):

```
result = var1 * 100 + var2 *10 + var3;
```

Comment: Now write a `N` finitely expandable version using C++ templates! JK +1

Comment: what if var1, var2 and var3 are not 1 digit numbers

Comment: @izomorphius well... this is still a combination of the three variables. Nowhere in the question does it say it has to be reversible.

Comment: it is a different question, not difficult to solve however

Answer (score 5):

printf("Result %d%d%d",var1, var2, var3);

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%d%d%d", var1, var2, var3);
sscanf(str, "%d", &result); // or atoi
```

Comment: Yes, but that isn't reversible, and sscanf has undefined behavior in the event of an overflow...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know how many digits do the vars have you will have to go through stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 12;
        int c = 2;
        stringstream ss;
        ss << a << b << c;
        int merge;
        ss >> merge;
        cout << merge << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Working example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/g3BxE).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need int variables ? Does string meet you requirements ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    int var1 = 1;
    int var2 = 2;
    int var3 = 3;

    ostringstream oss;
    string result;

    oss<<var1<<var2<<var3;

    result = oss.str();
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```